# Is there a way to refresh the page with jquery without doing a location.reload()?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a script that checks to see if two or more options are alike.  If they are alike I prevent the page from being submitted.  It works but only if I refesh the page after the alert message is displayed.  If I select a favoriable option the error alert is still in memory except I refresh the page.

I supose I can do ‘location.reload()’ but the user is left waiting for the page to be reloaded.  Is there something I can do to refresh the page without doing a location.reload()?  Here’s my script:

```
$("#saveBtn").click(function () {

    for (var x = 0; x < checkedindex.length; x++) {
        var ind = checkedindex[x];

        var dateofclass = $(".TextBoxDate:eq(" + ind + ")");
        var timeofclass = $(".TextBoxTime:eq(" + ind + ")");
        var classday = $("select[name='searchString']:eq(" + ind + ")");

        classdate.push(dateofclass);
        classtime.push(timeofclass);
        dayofclass.push(classday);

        var testString = (dayofclass[x].val() + classtime[x].val()).toString();


        if (testString.indexOf(oldDateAndTime) == 0)//returns -1 if no match is found 0 means a match was found…. there are two or more of the same string
        {
             alert("Please make the correct selection");
             return false;
        }
        oldDateAndTime = (dayofclass[x].val() + classtime[x].val()).toString();
     }
 });
```

Comment: @RohitBatham, read question tag...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following are the 535 ways of reloading a page using javascript

http://www.phpied.com/files/location-location/location-location.html

Answer (score 1):

```
 history.go(0);
```

Use history method